# Post loop for selected category

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display all posts from a selected category with thumbnail and title. I've managed to get the code below to show me the selected category, however I can't seem to figure out a loop to display the thumbnail and title for each post of that selected category.

```
<?php  $taxonomy = 'category'; 
// Get the term IDs assigned to post.
$post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );

// Separator between links.
$separator = ', ';

if ( ! empty( $post_terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {

    $term_ids = implode( ',' , $post_terms );

    $terms = wp_list_categories( array(
        'title_li' => '',
        'style'    => 'none',
        'echo'     => false,
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'include'  => $term_ids
    ) );

    $terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $terms ) ), $separator );

    // Display post categories.
    echo  $terms;

}  ?>
```

With this code I can get it to show me the thumbnail for the first post in that category:

```
<a href="<?php get_the_permalink($term_id); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(200, 200)); ?>
            </a>
```

How can I loop this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi if you want to select posts from specific categories try this [link](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-category-templates-in-wordpress/). It was kind of helpful for me.

Comment: Thank you so much. I looked through the link and I changed my code to match theirs, and it worked. I just had to change the layout a bit to match what I wanted.